# "Cannot move out of borrowed content" while summing command line arguments

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

It's my first Rust program and it seems I've already encountered the dreaded borrow checker. :)

The program should read the arguments passed in the command line, sum them and return the result. I have troubles parsing the arguments into integers.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let sum_args: i32 =
        args
        .iter()
        .skip(1)
        .fold(0, |a, &b| a + b.parse::<i32>().ok().expect("Not an i32!"));
    println!("{:?}", sum_args.to_string());
}
```

Which fails with:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:9:22
  |
9 |         .fold(0, |a, &b| a + b.parse::<i32>().ok().expect("Not an i32!"));
  |                      ^-
  |                      ||
  |                      |hint: to prevent move, use `ref b` or `ref mut b`
  |                      cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`args` is a `Vec<String>`, and the `iter` iterator returns references to strings (`&String`). One trick to see the types is to attempt to assign a value to the unit type `()`:

```
let () = args.iter().next();
```

Which has an error that shows the type:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
5 |         let () = args.iter().next();
  |             ^^ expected enum `std::option::Option`, found ()
  |
  = note: expected type `std::option::Option<&std::string::String>`
  = note:    found type `()`
```

In your closure, you are attempting to automatically dereference (`|a, &b|`) the second value. If you *were* able to dereference it, then the `String` would be *moved* out of the vector, which would leave the memory in the vector in an indeterminate state! If we tried to use the vector after this, we could cause a segfault, one of the things Rust is designed to help prevent.

The easiest thing is to not dereference it at all (leaving `b` as a `&String`):

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let sum_args: i32 =
        args
        .iter()
        .skip(1)
        .fold(0, |a, b| a + b.parse::<i32>().expect("Not an i32!"));
    println!("{:?}", sum_args.to_string());
}
```

Some additional minor points...

You don't have to specify the vector elements type when you `collect`:

```
let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
```

You don't need to create a string to print out a number:

```
println!("{}", sum_args);
```

And I'd probably have written it as

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let sum_args: i32 =
        args
        .iter()
        .skip(1)
        .map(|n| n.parse::<i32>().expect("Not an i32!"))
        .sum();
    println!("{}", sum_args);
}
```

---

**Overly clever solution warning**

If you had to sum up a bunch of iterators of potentially-failed numbers, you could create a type that implements `FromIterator` and doesn't allocate any memory:

```
use std::env;
use std::iter::{FromIterator, Sum};

struct SumCollector<T>(T);

impl<T> FromIterator<T> for SumCollector<T>
    where T: Sum
{
    fn from_iter<I>(iter: I) -> Self
        where I: IntoIterator<Item = T>
    {
        SumCollector(iter.into_iter().sum())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sum: Result<SumCollector<i32>, _> = env::args().skip(1).map(|v| v.parse()).collect();
    let sum = sum.expect("Something was not an i32!");
    println!("{}", sum.0);
}
```

---

Rust 1.16 should even support this out-of-the-box:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let sum: Result<_, _> = env::args().skip(1).map(|v| v.parse::<i32>()).sum();
    let sum: i32 = sum.expect("Something was not an i32!");
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

Comment: Isn't the vector supposed to be immutable by default though? I thought the borrowing thing was passing the ownership to the caller and then giving it back after it has been used. I need to re-read this portion then, thanks for the help!

Comment: The vector is immutable, that's true. Even if the vector were mutable, you wouldn't be allowed to move the value out like this - the state of the vector would still be in an inconsistent state. That's why there are specific methods on a vector to remove items safely. And borrowing doesn't transfer ownership, just like borrowing your friends car doesn't give you the title. ^_^